# Novacode DocX setting Checkbox value to Checked

Tags: docx

I have word template, that has check boxes. I named one of them "number1"(See attached picture) I want to know if there is a way in DocX that I can set the value of that checkbox to checked? The value is dependent on the data coming from DB.I cant find anything .
Thanks in advance for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM5Z1.png)